# Como pegar a string de um JSon pai ou de um JSon em formato de array?

Tags: android, json

Tenho o seguinte *JSON*:

```
String json = "{\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    \"Pessoas\":[\n" +
            "        {\n" +
            "            \"NomeHomem\":{\n" +
            "                \"Idade\":1\n" +
            "            }\n" +
            "        },\n" +
            "        {\n" +
            "            \"NomeMulher\":{\n" +
            "                \"Idade\":true\n" +
            "            }\n" +
            "        },\n" +
            "        {\n" +
            "            \"NomeCrianca\":{\n" +
            "                \"Idade\":\"string\"\n" +
            "            }\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "    ]\n" +
            "\n" +
            "}";
```

Quando não existe um array como neste caso eu uso um `getString("Pessoas");` e funciona. Mas e nesse caso, como fazer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considerando o seu JSON, abaixo:

```
{
   "Pessoas":[
      {
         "NomeHomem":{
            "Idade":1
         }
      },
      {
         "NomeMulher":{
            "Idade":true
         }
      },
      {
         "NomeCrianca":{
            "Idade":"string"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Como você bem observou agora temos um *array* de pessoas. Neste caso devemos recuperar como um [`JSONArray`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) e recuperarmos cada elemento, que aí será uma `Pessoa` e então recuperar seus valores, algo assim:

```
final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(json);
final JSONArray pessoas = json.getJSONArray("Pessoas");
final int pSize = pessoas.length();
for (int i = 0; i < pSize; i++) {
    final JSONObject pessoa = pessoas.getJSONObject(i);
    System.out.println(pessoa);
}
```

Neste caso o resultado obtido será este:

```
{"NomeHomem":{"Idade":1}}
{"NomeMulher":{"Idade":true}}
{"NomeCrianca":{"Idade":"string"}}
```

**EDIÇÃO**

Caso você queira também a string que representa *Pessoas* você pode chamar o `toString` de `JSONArray`, desta forma:

```
pessoas.toString();
```

Ou assim, que irá formatar a saída:

```
pessoas.toString(2);
```

A primeira forma irá gerar este resultado:

```
[{"NomeHomem":{"Idade":1}},{"NomeMulher":{"Idade":true}},{"NomeCrianca":{"Idade":"string"}}]
```

E a segunda este:

```
[
  {"NomeHomem": {"Idade": 1}},
  {"NomeMulher": {"Idade": true}},
  {"NomeCrianca": {"Idade": "string"}}
]
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas tem como recuperar também a String "pessoas"? eu precisava usar ela também.

Comment: @daniel12345smith atualizei a resposta, veja se é isto que precisa. Se não, atualize sua pergunta com o resultado esperado.

Comment: valew Bruno, com isso eu já consigo me virar aqui.