# Como pegar o nome das propriedades de um Objeto JavaScript ou JSON?

Tags: android, json

```
{
   "Ficha":[
      {
         "nome":"nome",
         "sobrenome":"sobrenome",
         "idade":"idade",
         "endereco":"endereco",
         "empresa":"empresa",
         "telefones":[
            {
               "residencial":"residencial"
            },
            {
               "celular":"celular"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Eu queria pegar o "Ficha" mas quando coloco um `getString("Ficha")` retorna o array completo.

Como faço para pegar só a string "Ficha" e depois pegar só a String "telefones"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está tentando pegar o nome da propriedade do objeto, você pode fazer algo assim:

```
var meuObjeto = {"carro": "civic", "casa": "fazenda"};
Object.keys(meuObjeto);
```

isso vai imprimir

```
["carro", "casa"]
```

Funciona no IE 9 ou superior.

Ou fazer um `for` pegando as chaves

```
for(var k in meuObjeto){
   console.log(k);
}
```

Funciona no IE 7 ou superior

No seu exemplo:

```
var json = {
   "Ficha":[
      {
         "nome":"nome",
         "sobrenome":"sobrenome",
         "idade":"idade",
         "endereco":"endereco",
         "empresa":"empresa",
         "telefones":[
            {
               "residencial":"residencial"
            },
            {
               "celular":"celular"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
};


 console.log(Object.keys(json));
```

imprime

```
["Ficha"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Esta questão sua é bem parecida com [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69932/como-pegar-a-string-de-um-json-pai-ou-de-um-json-em-formato-de-array) outra que você postou.

Considere verificar a documentação das classes do pacote [`org.json`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html), principalmente [`JSONObject`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) e [`JSONArray`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html). Mesmo assim veja se esta resposta abaixo lhe ajuda.

Novamente, vamos considerar o seu JSON, reproduzido abaixo:

```
{
  "Ficha":[
     {
        "nome":"nome",
        "sobrenome":"sobrenome",
        "idade":"idade",
        "endereco":"endereco",
        "empresa":"empresa",
        "telefones":[
           {
              "residencial":"residencial"
           },
           {
              "celular":"celular"
           }
        ]
     }
  ]
}
```

Temos um objeto não nomeado que contém um *array* de `Ficha`, então iremos construir a reprodução deste *JSON* como um `JSONObject`, desta forma:

```java
final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(json);
```

Depois disto iremos recuperar o *array* de `Ficha`, da seguinte forma:

```java
final JSONArray fichas = json.getJSONArray("Ficha");
```

Se imprimirmos o conteúdo de `fichas` usando `fichas.toString(2)` teremos a seguinte saída:

```
[{
  "idade": "idade",
  "endereco": "endereco",
  "nome": "nome",
  "sobrenome": "sobrenome",
  "empresa": "empresa",
  "telefones": [
    {"residencial": "residencial"},
    {"celular": "celular"}
  ]
}]
```

Se queres também o *array* de `telefones` terá antes que recuperar o `JSONObject` de `Ficha` e depois o `JSONArray` de `telefones`, algo desta forma:

```java
final JSONObject ficha = fichas.getJSONObject(i);
final JSONArray telefones = ficha.getJSONArray("telefones");
```

Ao imprimirmos o conteúdo de `telefones` usando `telefones.toString(2)` teremos a seguinte saída:

```
[
  {"residencial": "residencial"},
  {"celular": "celular"}
]
```

Este é um exemplo completo que gerou as saídas apresentadas:

```java
final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(getJSON());
final JSONArray fichas = json.getJSONArray("Ficha");

System.out.println(fichas.toString(2));

final int size = fichas.length();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
   final JSONObject ficha = fichas.getJSONObject(i);
   final JSONArray telefones = ficha.getJSONArray("telefones");
   System.out.println(telefones.toString(2));
}
```

**EDIÇÃO**

Para recuperar apenas os nomes do elementos existentes você pode usar os métodos [`names()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#names()) ou [`keys()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#keys())

Um exemplo usando `names()` é este:

```java
final JSONArray names = json.names();
final int nSize = names.length();
for (int i = 0; i < nSize; i++) {
    final Object name = names.get(i);
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

Que irá resultar nesta saída:

> Ficha

Já um usando `keys()` é este:

```java
final Iterator<String> iKeysIterator = json.keys();
while (iKeysIterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iKeysIterator.next());
}
```

Que irá resultar na mesma saída:

> Ficha

Veja se está disponível o método `keySet()` também, se estiver, você poderá usar da seguinte forma:

```java
final Set<String> keys = json.keySet();
for (final String key : keys) {
    System.out.println(key);
}
```

Comment: então, aquela outra resposta sua ajudou muito, eu consegui pegar o conteúdo do array tanto o ficha quanto o telefone, mas agora preciso pegar o nome do array, será que eu teria que nomear o array "Ficha" no json?

Comment: @daniel12345smith tem como atualizar sua resposta com o conteúdo que você espera? Tu quer recuperar a literal *Ficha* e *telefones*, é isso? Não entendi...

Comment: eu gostaria de recuperar apenas o nome do array "Ficha" e usar esse nome para colocar dentro de um textView, porque estou fazendo um formulário dinâmico. o "telefones" eu consigo pegar porque está dentro do array ficha, mas e o "Ficha" que é o nome principal? deve ser uma coisa simples, é que estou apanhando aqui.

Comment: @daniel12345smith resposta atualizada, veja se é isto

Comment: cara valeu, vou testar.

Comment: vou tentar com JS mesmo, já tava tentando resolver isso com JS.